# Where is the SIGSEGV error in my code and how to rectify it?

Tags: c, debugging

I want to solve this problem based on XOR. I used switch case to solve this, but this shows a runtime error SIGSEGV. How do I find the cause and rectify my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int s[1000]={0},q,x,c,j=1,min,temp,temp2;

    scanf("%d",&q);
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
     {
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c)
        {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d",&x);
            s[j]=x;
            j++;
            break;
        case 2:
            scanf("%d",&x);

            for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
            {
                s[k]=s[k]^x;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(s[0]==0)
                {
                    printf("%d\n",s[0]);

                }
            else
            {
                for(int k=1;k<j;k++)
                {
                    if(s[k]<s[k-1])
                        min=s[k];
                }
                printf("%d\n",min);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Using a debugger you can catch the crash as it happens, and locate where in your source it happens. Then you can also examine values of variables to see if any of them might be wrong.

Comment: try using a debugger to find the erroneous block. it will help you.

Comment: A few other things: First of all, test your code incrementally. By that I mean that you write some (a little piece of) code, and test it before writing the next piece of code. Also, sometimes you seems to be using one-based indexing and other times you seem to be using zero-based indexing. Which one is it? Then please learn how to use nice descriptive names of your variables. And use comments to describe what the code does, and why. Right now, we don't know what the code is supposed to do, or what problem it's supposed to solve.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What example input leads to a SIGSEGV for you?

Comment: The function `scanf()` has a return value for a reason, you ignore it at your own risk. Also, probably helpful: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: What happens if you init your `c` start of the loop with a default value (e.g. 0) and check that in your `switch` ?

Comment: it looks possible to go out of bounds on that array